# PL/SQL FOR Loop Error when Populating Dimension Table

Tags: oracle, loops, plsql, case

I am populating a dimension table named `TIMES` with data from an OLTP Table called `SALES` with the following code:

```
CREATE TABLE TIMES
(saleDay        DATE        PRIMARY KEY,
dayType         VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL);


BEGIN
    FOR rec IN 
        (SELECT saleDate, CASE WHEN h.hd IS NOT NULL THEN 'Holiday'
                WHEN to_char(saleDate, 'd') IN (1,7) THEN 'Weekend'
                ELSE 'Weekday' END dayType
        FROM SALES s LEFT JOIN 
            (SELECT '01.01' hd FROM DUAL UNION ALL
            SELECT '15.01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
            SELECT '19.01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
            SELECT '28.05' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
            SELECT '04.07' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
            SELECT '08.10' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
            SELECT '11.11' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
            SELECT '22.11' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
            SELECT '25.12' FROM DUAL) h
        ON h.hd = TO_CHAR(s.saleDate, 'dd.mm'))    
        LOOP
            INSERT INTO TIMES VALUES rec;
        END LOOP;
END;
/
```

When I run this, I'm getting the errors ORA-00001 (Unique Constraint Violation) and ORA-06512. I believe this is happening because the code is trying to input multiple dates (some of which are the same) into PK for my `TIMES` Dimension Table (`saleDay`). How would I implement a clause into this loop so it will only populate one instance of each `saleDate` into the `saleDay` PK so there isn't a violation?

For instance, If there are three rows in the `SALES` table where the `saleDate` is 2015-10-10, the code should only populate ONE instance of 2015-10-10 into the `saleDay` PK. I'm thinking the direction I should head is to implement a `WHILE` clause, however I'm not 100% sure on how that would work since this code is also using `CASE` to determine whether the `saleDay` was a Holiday, Weekday, or Weekend and populating the result into the `dayType` column.

Comment: add `distinct` keyword

Comment: Unrelated, but: you neither need PL/SQL nor a loop for this.

Comment: @I3rutt So something like: `SELECT DISTINCT saleDate, CASE WHEN h.hd IS NOT NULL THEN...`? This won't mess with the `CASE`? Unfortunately, I'm not at my DB so I can't test at the moment.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name totally agreed. I've been asked to complete via PL/SQL, so that's why I went this route. Would've been much easier with just SQL.

Comment: @I3rutt disregard. Built a quick schema in SQL Fiddle and it worked like a champ. For some reason I was thinking `DISTINCT` would mess with the `CASE` but it seems to work fine. Should have tried it before posting here. My apologies! Thanks though!

Comment: To answer your doubt: the rows will be built first, according to the `SELECT` list (including the `CASE` expression). The `DISTINCT` directive is applied only after all the rows are built - it is as if you wrote the query like this: `select distinct * from (select saledate, case ........)`.

Comment: Gotcha. Thanks for the clarification @mathguy

Comment: So I just ran this against my DB, and now I'm getting this: ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into ("CM420A01"."TIMES"."SALEDAY")
ORA-06512: at line 14. What is this from!?!?!?!?!

Comment: Disregard. Figured it out, just needed a `WHERE` clause to get rid of the `NULL` columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding `DISTINCT` resolved this. Originally thought `DISTINCT` would negatively impact the `CASE` but it doesn't. Thanks to I3rutt for pointing this out.

```
BEGIN
    FOR rec IN 
        (SELECT DISTINCT saleDate, CASE WHEN h.hd IS NOT NULL THEN 'Holiday'
                WHEN to_char(saleDate, 'd') IN (1,7) THEN 'Weekend'
                ELSE 'Weekday' END dayType
        FROM SALES s LEFT JOIN 
            (SELECT '01.01' hd FROM DUAL UNION ALL
            SELECT '15.01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
            SELECT '19.01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
            SELECT '28.05' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
            SELECT '04.07' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
            SELECT '08.10' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
            SELECT '11.11' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
            SELECT '22.11' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
            SELECT '25.12' FROM DUAL) h
        ON h.hd = TO_CHAR(s.saleDate, 'dd.mm'))    
        LOOP
            INSERT INTO TIMES VALUES rec;
        END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding `DISTINCT` as suggested in a Comment below your question is one way to solve the problem.

The following approach may be more efficient:

```
for rec in (select distinct saledate from sales)
loop
    insert into times (saleday, daytype) values
        (rec.saledate,   CASE .......);
end loop;
```

That is: put the CASE expression in the INSERT statement, not in the definition of the (implicit) cursor. There is no reason to compute the CASE expression multiple times for the same date, which may appear many times in the SALES table. There is no reason for the CASE expression to be part of the cursor, either. The CASE expression can use an IN condition (`case when to_char(rec.saledate, 'dd.mm') in ('01.01', '15.01', ....) then 'Holiday' when .......`)

Unless, of course, the homework problem specifically instructs you to use a left outer join....... :-(